# What is the equivalent syntax of LSF for this PBS command?

Tags: pbs, lsf

In PBS script, this allocates 4 CPUs on each of 4 nodes :

```
#PBS -l select=4:ncpus=4
```

How do I translate this into LSF command ?  I think the following will do :

```
#BSUB -n 16 -R "span[ptile=4]"
```

Am I correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to be right.   Pls see https://hpc.llnl.gov/banks-jobs/running-jobs/lsf-quick-start-guide .